# Is dark matter made from the particles that had charge but no mass in the early part of the Big Bang

Tags: dark-matter, big-bang-theory

It is assumed that massless charged  particles acquired mass after the early phase of the Big Bang. But could most charged particles be massless now as dark matter. They wouldn't interact with photons or electrons electromagnetically because electrons have mass and charge and photons are charge less massless Neither are charged massless

Comment: Dark matter particles (whatever they might be - axions, wimps something else...) must have mass, but no charge.  So the can't be particle with charge but no mass.

Comment: I would dispute the claim that dark matter particles have mass. The cold dark matter solution has problems associated with it such as too few dwarf galaxies. The hot model also has problems but doesn't as yet consider charged massless particles. If charged massless particles are like gluons (massless with colour charge) they could self interact and hold each other together.

Comment: But a key property of dark matter is that it has negligible self-interaction, apart from gravitation, which is due to mass. Haloes of such particles give the necessary mass distribution required to account for galaxy rotation curves. Charged massless particles would give a very different distribution.

Comment: What would be the point/need for massless "dark matter"?

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7905/massless-charged-particles

Answer (score 7):

Charged, massless particles would be a form of "hot" dark matter. i.e. A form of energy density that was relativistic at the epoch of structure formation and of course, still relativistic now, since massless particles travel at the speed of light. That is not what is needed to explain structure formation in the universe or the dynamical properties of galaxies and galaxy clusters now, which need "cold" (non-relativistic) dark matter.

However, a more fundamental problem appears to be that massless charged particles should not exist. If they did then electrons and positrons would quickly decay into their massless counterparts whilst conserving charge. Massless charged particles should also be rather easy to produce in particle accelerators and none have been observed. Indeed it should even be possible for "pair production" just to take place with everyday (visible) photons.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer!

Comment: @ProfRob The charged massless particles would not have interacted with the Higgs field in the early universe for some reason .That reason may also be why electrons and protons now can't decay into them and why visible photons can't form charged pairs  today .I should think that failure to interact with the Highs means a particle is carrying a quantum number (property) that is incompatible with the Highs field theory

Comment: @DaveTheWave  I gave an answer based on physics that is known. If you postulate physics from another universe then anything is possible. The reason I have given is essentially why muons are not common, everyday particles - all particles will decay to their least massive manifestation that does not violate conservation laws.

Comment: Minor point: "hot dark matter" traditionally refers to stuff that is nonrelativistic today (hence "matter"), but transitioned relatively recently so that it has a long free-streaming length and low phase-space density.

Answer (score 4):

No, because if "dark matter" had no mass, it wouldn't be dark matter anymore.

Keep in mind dark matter needs to exert gravitational force, and massless particles do not exert gravitational force (at least not in the same way massive particles do).

If dark matter actually did have no mass, it would become "dark radiation", which behaves in a fundamentally different way (see [Wikipedia's technical definition section for dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Technical_definition)). It's possible that a small amount of dark radiation exists, but not a lot of it, and certainly not anywhere near the amount of dark matter in the universe ([source](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.2767v1)).

Comment: I don't agree that massless charged particles would behave like radiation . The charge makes them different to light  and the masslessness different to baryons so they  may not move at the speed of light or slower They must be faster than light! Dark matter is more complicated than we think.